# Is PebbleTec / PebbleSheen pool surface worth the extra cost? Any alternatives?

Tags: pool

First time pool owner in the process of resurfacing a 15 year old pool.

We're getting sold hard on the PebbleSheen finish, but I'm not convinced it's worth the bump in cost. In searching online, it looks like there are a number of alternatives like:

- DiamondBrite
- Hydrazzo
- Quartz Plaster
- Wet Edge Primera Stone

Any thoughts? I need to make a decision in the next week and greatly appreciate your insight.

Answer (score 1):

Someone was recently selling me on a fresh water system for my pool as an alternative to my salt water (or chlorine) system. I asked him if there was a pool I could go off and swim in to see the difference and he said sure, come by his house. In the end I never went because I decided to not use that system for other reasons.

You are about to spend a lot of money on a pool surface and if you stay in that house for 5, 10, 15 years you will have to live with that decision for a long time. My advice is to ask each of the vendors if they have a sample pool that you (and your family) can try out to get a good feel for the surface. I have a pebble-tech finish and I could give you my opinion but it would be just that: My **Personal** opinion. What I like might not be what you and your family likes.

I hope this helps.

Comment: definitely a good tip, Guy. I'll be sure to ask... Mind sharing your personal opinion on the pebbletec surface? :)

Comment: Pros: Feels more natural and gives you the sense that you're swimming in a river or ocean. Looks fantastic. Cons: Can be rough on the skin. Algae attaches to it more easily.